# Looking for a term. In a square they are called quadrants, what can I call them in a hexagon?

Tags: geometry, definition

Imagine a square that you divide equally through the middle both vertically and horizontally. You then get 4 (square shaped) quadrants.

Imagine a square that you divide equally through the middle diagonally both ways. You then get 4 (triangle shaped) quadrants(?).

Now imagine a hexagon that you divide equally through the middle from the center of each edge. You then get 6 ("kite" shaped) *what*?

Even imagine a hexagon that you divide equally through the middle from each of the vertices. You then get 6 (triangle shaped) *what*?

Are the triangles in the square still called quadrants? What are they called in a hexagon? Hexants? I am currently just referring to them as triangles, but ideally you would imagine a plane divided into 6 open-ended triangles. How about sector? But that gives connotations of a circle.

I know octants exist, but that would be a cube/3d. Are these terms strictly limited to cartesian systems?

Comment: Welcome. By the way, *sextant* is a real device used in navigation but is not a word for a section of a six-sided object!